# UK Business (Creative - 06 months) Super Priority Visa Refusal

Tags: indian-citizens, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, business-travel, entertainment

[image]

I applied for a business (creative) entertainer visitor Visa because I am an octopad player, performing for 10 years in India. A London sponsor invited me to perform with my musical group in the Indian cultural festival of Navratri, Diwali and Gujarati New Year. The duration of the tour is 37 days.

I requested Super Priority visa service and was refused, for reasons I think are wrong. I attached all the sponsor documents with details of all expenses it will pay, their bank statements, charity registration certificate, and the events details.

I also attached my bank savings and current account statements, and my mother's pension and salary account statements. The refusal reasons are not correct:

1. Currency is not indicated: when we complete the online form in Gujarati language, it shows all the amounts in GBP. Is it compulsory to write it again?
2. Super Priority visa applied for just 6 days before date of travel: Is it necessory to say why? It takes 5 or more working days which will create problem for me as well as the sponsors making plans for performances; it's a society with 400 persons who daily gather to celebrate the festival,
3. Mention that NAPS will pay all the expenses and failure to submit evidence: this is totally wrong because I have attached sponsorship letter, agreement letter, and covering letter to the Embassy visa officer, the Society bank statements which has a good amount. I also got an invitation from Edinburgh Gujarati Society with a reference by Consul General Of India on their letterhead; they are agree to provide food and accommodation at their place, and London to London transportation.

Still, the visa officer informed me that I failed to submit documents, and asks why the Society would pay me because I am the chairman of an air academy. However, I also attached my biography about my business and that I am an octopad player and owner of this musical group. We perform on government contracts as well as private events. I attached many photographs of performances, YouTube links, international travelling photographs, original notaried work order of musical performance by the government of Gujarat etc. Still, it mentioned that my role in this trip is unclear.

4. Visa officer mentions a bank statement of my mother's pension account in which amount is very low, but I already stated that NAPS will provide all the expenses, including round trip air fare, visa fee, local hospitality in the UK etc. Why is the visa officer taking into account the applicant's bank statement?

If the visa officer is taking it into account, they didn't look at all the documents, because I attached my personal savings and current bank account statements, with a total of around 29Lakh Inr (19Lakh saving + 9 Lakh current). Is this not perfect?

We are getting everything from the sponsors in the UK. Why are they looking at whether that amount is sufficient or not? I have attached my mother's bank statement for support (her salary and pension account statement) which we are not using for any home expenses. I am earning so we do not require my mother's account. All the home expenses are paid by me; we are only 3 members in my family (me, my wife and my mother). I lost my father when I was 2 years old. My wife helps me in my business, so no need to take any money from mother's account; this is joint a family.

I need urgent help because 19 Sept 2017 is the travel date. What do I do now? Can I apply again? It is showing NRA in the refusal letter and mentions that it is not eligible for appeal or administrative review. I also applied online for administrative review on the same day of the refusal. All the documents are as were gotten from VHS Mumbai because it can verify if they want to confirm anything about the documents. I have cut a small part of the pouch and removed only the passport; there was no stamp so I was confused and saw a letter. So I removed the letter.

Comment: Even with a sponsors letter stating they will pay all costs, you are still considered under your own eligibility because the UK has no legal ability to force a sponsor to live up to their obligations.  Yes, you do have to provide a reason for not applying for the visa in an appropriate amount of time through the normal channels, otherwise everyone would simply apply for the priority visa and then it would be pointless to have that channel as an option.  Photographs et al are generally ignored because they can be easily faked and not so easily verified.

Comment: "Super Priority visa applied for just 6 days before date of travel: Is it necessary to say why?" A 37 day international musical tour is usually planned very far in advance. Sometimes years in advance. A visa officer who sees a non-professional musician (I say that not to attack your skills, which I'm sure are fantastic, but because your primary job appears to be at an "air academy") with an emergency need to travel to the UK to perform is going to rightfully confused. If you apply again, I would include some documentation as to why this is such a last-minute situation.

Comment: @Dorothy did you read the question? It appears that much of the evidence accompanying the application was ignored.  That situation is not present in the proposed duplicate question nor contemplated in the answer.

Comment: @phoog even if the evidence was ignored, it would probably still result in a similar refusal because the evidence that was supposedly ignored doesn't seem to fix most of the underlying concerns.

Comment: We should reopen this as @phoog says and also, the answer below is good and valuable IMO.

Answer (score 13):

A visa application and its supporting documents are like a Jigsaw puzzle, most of the things need to align correctly and sit in properly before they even start to look at whether to refuse or to accept this application. There is no rocket science involved, its plain simple everyday logic that can do you in.

For example, you mention you have big savings and you are a chairman of a music academy, why on earth did you submit your mother's pension statement as a supporting document? There was absolutely no need to present a document which was just going to give them more pieces of jigsaw which wouldn't fit in. Anybody who has sufficient savings and sufficient earnings does not need to provide parental support documents.

Think about it, you claim you have 32K GBP in your personal accounts and you presented your mothers account with GBP 606 balance. 606 is only 1.9% of what you have - why do you think her account statement was necessary here?

Ok, it is a big performance, if you don't make it there your sponsors will have troubles and so would you, fine. Then why did you not apply in time? You've not done enough planning for this trip. That is another piece of puzzle that does not fit. A visit needs to be well planned. An emergency to perform is no human rights emergency. For an ECO its not an emergency at all, nobody buys it.

> 4.Visa officer mentions a bank statement of my mother's pension account in which amount is very low, but I already stated that NAPS will provide all the expenses, including round trip air fare, visa fee, local hospitality in the UK etc. Why is the visa officer taking into account the applicant's bank statement?

What if the applicant runs away in the UK? The applicant himself/herself needs to prove a need to return to their home country, regardless of whether they are going to be given a 7 star accommodation in the UK.

Every applicant, including me, when gets rejected feels that the onus was on the ECO and that they didn't consider the proper evidence submitted. But that is very rarely the case. That's their everyday job and there are too many checks and balances to miss such important details frequently.

However, if you genuinely believe that for some reason they did not consider your other supporting documents and you're sure they will build a good support for your case the only option is to apply again (There is no appeal for a Visit Visa refusal) and in your new application do address the reasons for your prior refusal and do mention that you submitted all the supporting documentation which was seemingly ignored.

Make all the pieces of the puzzle fit in smoothly, then even if some are missing you have good chances of approval. This situation, as you have described here, is just not convincing. It does not even convince a most ordinary person like me, let alone a sharp eyed ECO.

Every claim that you make, every supporting document that you present, every question that you answer all these things need to build support for your main application, everything needs to slowly build support for your case. Don't present contradictions. That's the advice